# The incrementing here continues to return a 0 value

Tags: python, recursion

I was writing the solution to [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55bf01e5a717a0d57e0000ec/train/python) codewars problem however I've ran into a bit of an issue.

Problem statement:

> Write a function, `persistence`, that takes in a positive parameter `num` and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in `num` until you reach a single digit, e.g.:
>
> `persistence(39)` # returns 3, because 3*9=27, 2*7=14, 1*4=4 and 4 has only one digit

```
def persistence(n, t=1, x=0):
    if len(str(n)) > 1:
        number = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
        for i in number:
            t = t * i
        if len(str(t)) > 1:
            x += 1
            return(persistence(t,x))
        else:
            return(x)
    else:
        return 0
```

I can't quite figure out what the error is in this code. My hunch is that it's either a parameter error or the way the return() value is placed.

In essence, the code for distilling an integer to it's multiples is correct, so I just added an extra parameter to persistence; setting x = 0 and making it so that each time the if condition was fulfilled it would increment that exact x value. Once the number was distilled, simply output x. Yet it continues to simply output 0 as the final answer. What's the problem here?

Edit: Solution was in the comments, didn't realise how the parameters were passing. Correct version is:

```
return(persistence(t,1,x))
```

Also had to set x = 1 for the logic to work on codewars.

Comment: `return(persistence(t,x))` Are you aware that `t` will be passed as the `n` argument, and `x` will be passed as `t`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah, I suspected this had something to do with the parameters. I knew that t was passing as n since the code requires that but I hadn't thought the following parameters would be in order as well. I'm presuming the correct version would be persistence(t,1,x)

Comment: `t` should really be a local variable and not a parameter. And instead of using `x`, you can just `return 1 + persistence(t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 flaws in Your code:

```
return(persistence(t,x))
```

should be

```
return(persistence(t,1,x))
```

otherwise the value of x will be assigned to t and x will be defaulted to 0.

Then you must increment x directly after the first test, otherwise You will miss one iteration.

Another way to calculate this is not to switch over to strings, but to do it numerically:

```
def persistence(n):
    iterations = 0;           # no iterations yet
    while n > 9:              # while n has more than 1 digit:
        product = 1              # neutrum for result product
        while n > 0:             # while there a digit to process:
            digit = n % 10          # retrieve the right most digit
            product *= digit        # do the multiplication
            n = n // 10             # cut off the processed digit
        iterations += 1          # increment iterations
        n = product              # let n be the newly calculated product
    return iterations         # return the result
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you your function's parameters work not as you expect them to do.
When you call function `persistence(t, x)`, the first argument `n` should become `t`, and second argument `x`, should become new `x`. But in your function, `x` becomes new `t` because of their position.

It is quite useful to have bunch of `print` statements to reveal the bug.

```py
def persistence(n, x=1, t=1):
    print('x:', x)
    if len(str(n)) > 1:
        number = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
        for i in number:
            t = t * i
        print('t:', t)
        if len(str(t)) > 1:
            x += 1
            print('x has changed:', x)
            return persistence(t, x)
        else:
            return x
    else:
        return 0


print(persistence(39))
print('---------------')
print(persistence(999))
print('---------------')
print(persistence(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passes all test cases with two changes:

- You were not updating your `n` with the new `t` everytime
- Your x was being set to 0 every time. That should be set to 1 in the beginning (default value)

  ```
  def persistence(n, t=1, x=1):
    if len(str(n)) > 1:
        number = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
        for i in number:
            t = t * i
        if len(str(t)) > 1:
            x += 1
            return (persistence(n=t, x=x))
        else:
            return (x)
    else:
        return 0
  ```

Actually, you can write it without needing both parameters `t` and `n`. Just one `n` is fine as shown below:

```
def persistence(n, x=1):
    if len(str(n)) > 1:
        number = [int(i) for i in str(n)]

        t = 1
        for i in number:
            t = t * i

        if len(str(t)) > 1:
            return x + (persistence(n=t, x=x))
        else:
            return (x)
    else:
        return 0
```